# coverage.py doesn't work with relative imports?

Tags: python, django, coverage.py, django-nose

I am gathering the code coverage for my django app and looks like `coverage.py` doesn't collect the statistics if the module was imported relatively.

More detailed:

the directory structure looks like this:

```
project
    __init__.py
    apps
        __init__.py
        my_app
            __init__.py
            my_module.py
            tests.py
```

So if I do `from .my_module import *` in `tests.py` - then `coverage.py` won't gather the statistics for `my_module.py`. However, if I put `from apps.my_app.my_module import *`, the statistics is there.

I am using [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) with `coverage` plugin and have `--cover-package=apps.my_app` flag while running tests.

Has anybody stumbled upon such? I don't really want to always have the full import path, unless I really have to, so any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with django-nose, but to resolve a similar problem without Django I installed pytest and pytest-cov packages and did something similar to:

```
py.test --cov app
```

which reported the coverage.